# Is there an app that allows me to login to and manage multiple IE sessions under different user accounts?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-strategy, ie11

I’m testing an `intranet web app` on `IE11` and need to open about 8 browsers, each under a different `login ID`.

It’s hard to navigate through 6-8 separate IE windows so I was wondering if there’s an app, that can contain all my different sessions via tabs, that I can click on to select, which session to focus on.

If there’s a better solution for this, I’d be very happy to try it.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why do you need 8 different users / sessions?

Answer (score 1):

While performing testing in software testing solutions, there are methods to maintain the sessions on the browser. A feature of Internet Explorer 8 called 'Private Browsing mode' gives us a completely independent session with no shared cookies and manage multiple accounts. In order to enable it, simply press CTRL+SHIFT+P from IE browser in your computer.

While testing in Chrome browser in functional testing services, there is a plug-in named 'SessionBox' which could be added in order to manage sessions on the same browser.

Answer (score 0):

For software testing solutions to manage multiple browser sessions, Private Window or Incognito Mode is recommended that can help while performing multiple functional testing tasks across different browsers.